# Push Elements into an array inside a class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

i am trying to make a plugin through Worpress, i have in the frontend a list of generated plugins
like so [Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3plpp.jpg)

what i am trying to do is to get these plugins to be stored into an array inside the class and be printed or processed inside any function or a callback if i clicked submit. and here is the code.

```
class Example {

    private static $init_core_plugins = array();

    private static function handle_post() {
        $save_settings = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'save_settings' );
                if ( !is_null( $save_settings ) && check_admin_referer( 'save-settings' ) ) {
                    self::save_settings();
                    self::refresh_page();
                    }
                }

    private static function save_settings() {
    $core_plugins = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'coreplugins', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
                if ( empty( $core_plugins ) ) {
                    $core_plugins = [];
                }
                self::$init_core_plugins = array_merge( $core_plugins, self::$init_core_plugins );
                // it shows here that it holds the correct selected plugins
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump (self::$init_core_plugins);
                echo "</pre>";
                update_option( 'core_plugins_settings', $core_plugins );
                }
                
    public static function admin_render_main_page(){
                 // it shows here that it is an empty array
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump (self::$init_core_plugins);
                echo "</pre>";  
                }
}
```

What i am facing is somehow simple problem but i can't figure out where is the problem, when i called the array inside var_dump() inside save_settings() it printed the selected plugins from the list normally, but the problem is when later i try to var_dump (self::$init_core_plugins) in any other function like in the admin_render_main_page(), it returns as empty array, and the passed data through the save_settings() doesn't seem to be stored in the array.

Comment: `save_settings()` isn't running inside `admin_render_main_page()` though? So the list of plugins wouldn't ever get saved to it... is there some reason you have to use static methods instead of setting the variable in a setter method or the constructor? Otherwise you'll have to add `self::$init_core_plugins = array_merge( $core_plugins, self::$init_core_plugins );` to the `admin_render_main_page()` method as well.

Comment: I got ur point here , but what i am trying to do , is to have an array outside any functions and then be able to add elements to it through other functions. And whenever i call this array in anywhere in the code. I expect the pushed elements not the empty array

Comment: Right but in your example, there's nothing that updates the value of `$init_core_plugins` inside the admin function, so it would just display the default empty array. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Otherwise you'll have to repeat the code that sets the variable inside the admin function, or create a separate function that merges the arrays and use it in all the other functions.

Comment: Or use non-static methods and a constructor that sets it.

Comment: i have opened another question in details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152654/insert-data-to-an-array-property-using-a-method-within-the-same-class